# bat to delete files if they contain in their source code phrases saved in a list

Tags: list, batch-file, delete-file

I need a batch files to delete more files which contain within them a series of words/phrase saved in a text list.

Path of folder with files to delete

```
D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\log
```

File have different name but end with .log

```
1.log
2.log
3.log
4.log
```

Path with text list with phrases

```
D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\ip_used.csv
```

Content of ip_used.csv

```
111.111.111.111
62.10.10.10
124.100.100.100
84.225.222.222
200.200.200.222
```

Content of 1.log

```
THIS IS TEXT
BLA BLA BLA
IP ADDRESS 111.111.111.111
TEXT TEST
```

Content of 2.log

```
THIS IS TEXT
BLA BLA BLA
IP ADDRESS 62.10.10.10
TEXT TEST
```

Content of 3.log

```
THIS IS TEXT
BLA BLA BLA
IP ADDRESS 99.100.100.100
TEXT TEST
```

Content of 4.log

```
THIS IS TEXT
BLA BLA BLA
IP ADDRESS 50.50.50.50
TEXT TEST
```

After i run the bat it search the used ip (saved in ip_used.csv) checking the source of log files and delete when find same ip.

After run the bat will be erased 1.log because contain in the sources 111.111.111.111 and will be erased 2.log because contain in the sources 62.10.10.10.

111.111.111.111 and 62.10.10.10 are saved in used_ip.csv.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /M /G:"D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\ip_used.csv" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\log\*.log"') do del "%%a"`

Comment: Working great, many thanks excellent work, thanks again. Bye